# long text in php doesn't appear correctly with html

Tags: html, php-5.5

I would like to see a long text that was selected from the databases, but it appears on a single line and it is not complete, i.e., no return to the line. If I try to manually type the text instead of the variable, it works very well.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Discussion</h2>
        <h4><a href="school.php">School</a></h4>
        <p><?php echo $question;?></p>
        <p><label style="color: gray"> 13/03/2016 </label></p> 
</div>
```

Comment: How are you inserting the `$question` into the database?

Comment: it's a textarea , I inserted it by 'Insert...' in a column varchar(..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `nl2br()` while inserting the data into the database.

```
$text = nl2br(htmlentities($input, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

This will preserve the whitespace while storing into the database. Use it in the `insert` function.